# Use literal style on scalar values for YAML serialization with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I am using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to serialize objects to YAML ([jackson-dataformat-yaml](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) library).

I would like to produce [literal style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844) output for scalar values (e.g. 'description' in the following example) like

```
---
id: 4711
description: |
  FooBar
  HelloWorld
```

but I only manage to produce quoted scalars like this:

```
---
id: 4711
description: "FooBar\nHelloWorld"
```

The code I use to generate the ObjectMapper is (by now) very simple:

```
    YAMLFactory f = new YAMLFactory();
    f.enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES); // setting does not matter
    ObjectMapper objectMapperYaml = new ObjectMapper(f);
    String yaml = objectMapperYaml.writeValueAsString(someObject);
```

I guess there is some possibility to generate literal style scalar values but I don't know how. Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would be using SNAKEYaml on it's own it would be a matter of setting the corresponding dumper option:

```
DumperOptions dumperOptions = new DumperOptions();
dumperOptions.setDefaultScalarStyle(ScalarStyle.LITERAL);
```

Sadly enough it can't be done through a JacksonFeature here.

A quick glance through the source however show that the feature to enable is `MINIMIZE_QUOTES`, you'll find their algorithm in `YAMLGenerator#writeString`.

So here's the full class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLGenerator;

public class NewClass {

    private int id;

    private String description;

    public static void main(String... a) throws JsonProcessingException {
        YAMLFactory f = new YAMLFactory();
        f.enable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.MINIMIZE_QUOTES);
        ObjectMapper objectMapperYaml = new ObjectMapper(f);

        final NewClass someObject = new NewClass();
        someObject.setId(4711);
        someObject.setDescription("Hallo\nWorld!");
        System.out.println(objectMapperYaml.writeValueAsString(someObject));
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an year old thread but this was the top link suggested by Google and it needs an update.

The literal style is supported by Jackson since v.2.9. There is an issue though with trailing spaces as in this [bug](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/issues/440/literal-style-dump-trailing-space-prevents)

Example:

```java
YAMLMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
mapper.configure(YAMLGenerator.Feature.LITERAL_BLOCK_STYLE, true);
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("literal_ok", "some value\n wih\n   multiple\n    new lines\nin it");
map.put("can_not_use_literal", "can not\n   use literal    \b because of the trailing spaces");
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
```